# mysql to mongodb database and query conversion

Tags: mongodb

The following structure as defined in MySQL db

> 1. I have a one table for degree
>        contain two columns : degree_id ,degree_name
>      2.Another Table for branch
>      branch_id,branch_name,degree_id
>      3.Subject table
>      subject_id,subject_name,subject_code,degree_id,semester
>      4.syllabus

```
syllabus_id,syllabus_name,sort_note,attachment,semester,degree_id,branch_id,subject_id
```

Now i can easily fetch the syllabus of particuler degree,branch,semester using mysql but i am new in mongo db please help

Comment: It would be better if you describe the one-to-one and one-to-many relationship between the entities. For example I am guessing syllabus and subject has one to one relationship and one branch will have many subject. but I am not sure about the relationship of degree and  branch. Can one branch have multiple degree or vice-versa?

Comment: Question is from 2013 you still on it m8 lel

Answer (score 0):

In `MongoDb` you have to take the concept more general and include all the relation in it.

Your database `Mysql`, looks like this on `mongodb`:

```
     degree{
            _id : ...,
            name : ...,
            branches :[ {
                         _id: ...
                         name: ....,
                         syllabus : [ {
                                       _id: ...,
                                       name: ....,
                                       sort_note: ....
                                       attachment:...
                                       semetster,... 
                                      } , ..   ],...{
                       } ],
             subjects: [ {
                          _id: ..,
                          name: ....,
                          code: .....,
                          semester: ....
                       }, ...]
             }
```

If id_branch and id_degree are uniques like a contraint is an object else is an array.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your data model for SQL and for me something is not quite clear.
It seems you add your degree to every collection (branch/subject/syllabus).

I guess you eventually query your syllabus on degree_id (branch_id/subject_id) at the highest level for example

```
select * from syllabus where degree_id = ?
```

or

```
select * from syllabus where branch_id = ?
```

This means you do NOT search a syllabus by degree_id set on a branch or subject like this

```
select s.* from syllabus s
join branch b on b.branch_id = s.branch_id
join subject su on su.subject_id = s.subject_id
where b.degree_id = ? // or su.degree_id = ?
```

So let's say you do search your syllabus collection by the degree_id that is set for a syllabus record.
It makes it easier to get the same result in MongoDB.

The easiest way to translate your current SQL model into a MongoDB model you could have 4 collections instead of 4 tables.

degrees

```
{
   degree_id : ...
   degree_name : ...
}
```

branches

```
{
   branch_id : ...
   branch_name : ...
   degree : {
      degree_id : ...
      degree_name : ...
   }
}
```

same for subjects and eventually same way for syllabus having a degree, branch and subject document embedded into a syllabus document.
MongoDB does not need fixed relations or foreign keys and does not have JOINS like in a relational database. So you either embed the other collections or you add a reference to the documents by the _id field (just like SQL), depending on what your query result should look like in the end.

Embedding the other collections your syllabus collection would look like this

```
[
   {
   _id : ObjectId('syllabus_id_1'), //_id or syllabus_id but MongoDB adds an _id field automatically,
   syllabus_name : 'syllabus1',
   sort_note : 'a note',
   attachment : 'my attachment',
   semester : 'semester1',
   degree : {
      degree_id : ObjectId('degree_id_1'),
      degree_name : 'degree1'
   },
   branch : {
      branch_id : ObjectId('branch_id_1'),
      branch_name : 'branch1',
      degree : {
         degree_id  : ObjectId('degree_id_1'),
         degree_name : 'degree1'
      }
   },
   subject : {
      subject_id : ObjectId('subject_id_1'),
      subject_name : 'subject1',
      subject_code : 'code',
      semester : 'semester1',
      degree : {
         degree_id  : ObjectId('degree_id_1'),
         degree_name : 'degree1'
      }
   }
   }
]
```

This way you could query your syllabus collection like this

```
syllabus.find({'degree.degree_id':ObjectId('degree_id_1'), 'degree.degree_name':'degree1'})
```

or

```
syllabus.find({'branch.branch_id':ObjectId('branch_id_1'), 'branch.branch_name':'branch1'})
```

Or you link to the other collections with only the _id fields in which case your syllabus document would look like this

```
[
   {
   _id : ObjectId('syllabus_id_1'), //or syllabus_id but MongoDB adds an _id field automatically,
   syllabus_name : 'syllabus1',
   sort_note : 'a note',
   attachment : 'my attachment',
   semester : 'semester1',
   degree : ObjectId('degree_id_1'),
   branch : ObjectId('branch_id_1'),
   subject : ObjectId('subject_id_1'),
   }
]
```

You can only query your syllabus by the id fields like this

```
syllabus.find({degree:ObjectId('degree_id_1')})
```

or

```
syllabus.find({degree:ObjectId('branch_id_1')})
```

I hope you understand the concept and decide which approach is better for your application. It all depends on what your syllabus document should look like in your query result.

In my applications I always think about the queries first and then model my documents.

You should always keep in mind that you do not have JOINS, there are plugins to give you some sort of joining and predefined model layout like Mongoose. But in my opinion that is completely against what is MongoDB about. Try to model your data in a MongoDB way:-)

Please let me know if something is not clear.